# Any way to adjust a button built with interface builder to reverse when tapped?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios7, interface-builder

I am not a huge fan of interface builder but I am trying to create a UIButton that would highlight when touched. I was thinking the whole button to reverse. I see this property `reverses on highlight` but what it does is to reverse the text. I want the whole button to reverse color.

This is how I have it now:

[image]

This is a green button with rounded corners. Is there a way to make the whole button to reverse from interface builder?

This is an iOS 7 only project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep things inside interface builder, I believe your only option is to configure different background images for each button state. I had the same problem and couldn't find a way to use different `UIColor`s for different button states. If your button style is really minimal, you could potentially use 1x1 pngs and apply rounded corners using Quartz directly in code.

In my case, I ended up creating a custom subclass of `UIButton` with a setter to configure  different colors/text colors and shadows for each state (I used an enum to map different button "themes").